# How to implement form validations for Dynamically generated Form fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a page in my Angular application where all form fields are created dynamically based on data coming from backend.

```
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="form-inline" name="reportsForm">
                        <div class="form-group form-group-grid" ng-repeat="fields in selectedTabData.requiredField" ng-switch="fields.paramType">
                            <label>{{fields.paramName}}<span class="asterisk" ng-if="fields.mandatory==true">*</span></label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="Number" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-required="fields.mandatory">
                            <input type="date" data-date-format="mm/DD/YYYY" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="DatePicker" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-required="fields.mandatory">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="Text" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-required="fields.mandatory">
                            <select type="date" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="DropDown" ng-options="field.paramKey as field.paramValue for field in fields.paramData" ng-model="fields.fieldValue" ng-required="fields.mandatory">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-inline-grid-button" ng-click="getReport()">Run Report</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <span  style="color:red">Please enter all the required fields marked with (*)</span>
                </div>
```

I need the validation error message to be shown if anyone of the required field in the form is left empty.

The form fields data coming from backend is assigned in `$scope.selectedTabData.requiredField`

```
$scope.selectedTabData.requiredField.forEach(function(item)
        {
            if(item.paramType == "DatePicker")
            {
                var date = new Date(item.fieldValue);
                var formattedDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
                paramValue.push(formattedDate);
                paramName.push(item.paramName);
            }
            else
            {
                if(item.mandatory == true && item.fieldValue == undefined){
                    //need to set validation as failed
                }else{
                    //need to set validation as passed
                }
                paramValue.push(item.fieldValue);
                paramName.push(item.paramName);
            }
        })
```

This is the condition I need to check to validate the form :

```
if(item.mandatory == true && item.fieldValue == undefined){
                    //need to set validation as failed
                }else{
                    //need to set validation as passed
                }
```

This is the first time I am working with dynamic fields, can anyone help me with implementation of validation in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix this, I had to deal with this the basic way.

I created a scope variable and set it as a flag.

in HTML :

```
<div>
<span ng-if="formInvalid" style="color:red">Please fill in all the required fields(*)</span>
</div>
```

In Controller :

```
$scope.formInvalid = false; 

if(item.mandatory == true && item.fieldValue==null)
            {
                $scope.formInvalid = true;
            }
```

This worked out for me. Please add more answers if you have an alternate solution to handle validations in dynamic elements.